# Function's return type as union of objects properties types

Tags: typescript

Somewhat new to TS. Wanted to type a function whose return type is union of objects properties types like this:

```
get({age:9,name:"Nick"})
// Return type should be number | string
```

Tried this:

```
let get = <T extends {age:number, name:string}>(x:T):T[keyof T]=>{  
   return x.age
}
```

But errors on `x.age`:

> Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'T[keyof T]'

When I return `null as any` from function the functions return type was correctly inferred though.

Why I get that error?

Comment: IDK why but I got around it like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WzPzeN)...

Comment: @caTS I see but would be better to know why mine doesn't work or why did yours work...

Comment: I'm not sure what the use case is for such a function, but the issue is that the compiler tends to widen generics when reading non-generic properties, as mentioned [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33181#issuecomment-526916194).  The workaround would be to explicitly annotate the indexing as generic, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/Naro2m).  Does that fully address the question? If so I will write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing? (Pls mention @jcalz to ping me if you reply)

Comment: @jcalz Not sure I understood reason for the error completely, I think it has to do with this: " Once you fall back to something concrete you can't later index with something generic.". But if you can explain, yeah feel free to answer. About use case, yeah I don't have use case, was just playing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dealing with operations on [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html)-typed values, there is a tradeoff the compiler needs to make.  Either the result of the operation can stay generic, which produces potentially very precise and accurate types, but such complex generic types are difficult for the compiler to analyze; or the generic type can first be widened to its [constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) so that the resulting type is specific, which is easier to analyze but can lead to a loss of precision.  The compiler uses heuristic rules to determine when to propagate generics and when to widen to specifics.

For example, inside

```
let get = <T extends { age: number, name: string }>(x: T) => {
  const age = x.age // what type is age?
  return age;
}
```

what type should `age` be?  Since `x` is of type `T`, and you are indexing into it with a key of type `"age"`, then the precise generic type of `x` is the [indexed access type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) `T["age"]`.  On the other hand, we know that `x`'s type is a subtype of `{age: number, name: string}`.  And so we can widen `x` to that type, in which case the type of `x.age` is `{age: number, name: string}["age"]`, which is just `number`.  So the two obvious possibilities here are: either `age` stays generic and is of type `T["age"]`, or it is widened to a more immediately usable specific type `number`.

What does the compiler do?

```
let get = <T extends { age: number, name: string }>(x: T): T[keyof T] => {
  const age = x.age;
  // const age: number
  return age; // error! Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'T[keyof T]'.
}
```

It is widened to `number`.  This behavior is documented in [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33181#issuecomment-526916194) on [microsoft/TypeScript#33181](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33181), a similar issue to the one you're seeing.  Paraphrasing slightly:

> Property access and element access return the corresponding property type of the constraint, so [ `x.age` has type `number` ], this is why the the [ `return` statement ] fails. Once you fall back to something concrete you can't later index with something generic.

That is, when you return `age`, the compiler will see that you've returned a value of type `number`.  And unfortunately, `number` is not necessarily assignable to `T[keyof T]`, as shown here:

```
interface Centenarian {
  name: string,
  age: 100,
}
declare const oldManJenkins: Centenarian;
const g = get(oldManJenkins);
// const g: string | 100
```

A `Centenarian` has an `age` which is the always the [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) `100`, which is narrower than `number`.  Inside `get()` the compiler has widened `age` from "whatever `T["age"]` turns out to be" to `number`, and `number` is not assignable to `string | 100` (because, say, `99.5` is a `number`, but it's not a `string | 100`).

So that's why you get the error.

---

As for how to deal with it, you can do something similar to what's shown in microsoft/TypeScript#33181... explicitly [annotate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) an `age` variable with the desired generic type, so the compiler has a hint not to widen it:

```
let get = <T extends { age: number, name: string }>(x: T): T[keyof T] => {
  const age: T['age'] = x.age; // okay
  return age; // okay
}
```

Now `age` is seen to be of type `T['age']`, which is seen to be assignable to `T[keyof T]`, and the function compiles without error.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.4#code/DYUwLgBA5uELwQDwBUIgB5hAOwCYGcIBvCAQxgC4JsBXAWwCMQAnAGmtLpCvzGYEtsUCAF8AfAAp0VZAEoZAbQDWIAJ4B7AGYRkAXXhjiAKAgQAxuuy8IAfXIh4EdADp7EAPTvq9JsxPnLa3tFAHJ7EP0EF3sAbg8vdSVSVX9mcBpmbDIYOM8IROSjESMjQSxmTVIzBwBhHCxsUgFSLKJ-Rq4ePkEoVn9giABGAAZhvuLcEDNgJocLK0h1YFwAWRaAKRwlQXwqOuwGpv4WmKN562EEGDAJJdWNrZ3ZU7zzyCgugSEIAB8h0aAA)

Comment: @jcals I think there is typo here "...is the always the literal type 100, which is narrower than *string*" --> should be `number` instead of `string`? Also that paragraph has some formatting issues IMHO. Other than that thanks for the elaborate answer.

Comment: Yeah oops, fixed.

Comment: one more question about your solution. When you write `const age: T['age'] = x.age; `, if my understanding is correct type of `x.age` is `number`, however, type of `T['age']` should `extend` `number`. So why does TS not complain when assigning `number` to something that `extends number`?

Comment: Maybe it should complain, but such unsoundness is left there to support such cases.  Ideally the compiler would infer `x.age` as type `T['age']` and then possibly *widen* to `number`, and if you use an annotation it would not widen it.  (Like how you can write `let x = "abc"` and `x` will be widened to `string`, but `let x: "abc" = "abc"` will not widen.  If you wrote `let x: "abc" = "def"` there would be an error.)  But for generics I think it actually does allow unsound assignments, likely for performance reasons.